# PHP - Autoload and Namespace without Composer

Tags: php

Im coming from the oldest way to include a PHP using multiple require etc...

I've tried several autoload tutorials but I get always an error:

My directory struture is very simple:

```
- test.php
- models
   |
   - MyClass.php
```

MyClass is very simple:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject;
class MyClass
{
  // code
}
```

And test.php is:

```
namespace MyProject;

set_include_path (".");

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    $file_name = get_include_path()."/".$class_name . '.php';
    $file_name = str_replace("\\","/",$file_name);

    if( file_exists( $file_name ) ) {
        echo "Trying to include ".$file_name;
        require ($file_name);
    }
    else {
        echo "file not found";
    }
});

use models\MyClass as MyClass;

$foo = new MyClass();
```

"file not found" is not printed so the Class file is found.
I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'models\MyClass' not found in test.php
```

Using the oldest method with:

```
require ('models/MyClass.php');
$foo = new MyClass();
```

it works.

I searched on internet but this is the standard ways to autoload and seems works to everyone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file is found but the namespace is wrong. Try `namespace models;` in MyClass.php.

Comment: You're in a namespace `Geos2`, plus MyClass is in `MyProject` namespace. What am I doing wrong? Your not using composer.

Comment: I updated the post because naming was obviously an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things. You have a namespace MyProject in MyClass. So you should reference the class as MyProject\MyClass.

You structure should be:

- test.php
- models/MyProject

  |

  - MyClass.php

test.php should be:

```
<?php
namespace Geos2;

set_include_path(__DIR__.'/models');

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    $file_name = get_include_path()."/".$class_name . '.php';
    $file_name = str_replace("\\", "/", $file_name);
    if (file_exists($file_name)) {
        echo "Trying to include ".$file_name;
        require_once($file_name);
    } else {
        echo "file not found";
    }
});

use MyProject\MyClass as MyClass;

$foo = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace in the `MyClass.php` is wrong

You must use the correct namespace

```
namespace models;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (PHP package management tool) for it instead. So after installing `composer` you can run composer `composer init`and answer couple of those project related question then run `composer install` . You will get a composer.json file where you can add where to find the classes . I would also suggest you to familiarize with PSR-0 and PSR-4 e.g.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyClass\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

This way if you create any class inside the source directory then it can be included(maybe not the right term) as `use MyClass\Model` when you have Model.php class inside the src directory . If you have a directory called `Utility` inside `src` directory and `Utility` has `MyUtility` class then you can include it as `use MyClass\Utility\MyUtility` and `MyUtility` class can have namespace `MyClass\Utility`.

If you run composer install then it will generate vendor directory which will contain `autoload.php` . This way you need not write your own autoloader every place but include it once at the entry point of the project and most php projects I have seen use this way for package management and auto loading.

These are some of my first attempts to answer questions at stackoverflow . So please correct me or suggest me if I have made mistake on my answer. I would like to improve or get feedback.